# Prove that: $\mathrm{cosec} \frac {\alpha}{8}...$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that:
$$\mathrm{cosec}\frac {\alpha}{8}+\mathrm{cosec}\frac {\alpha}{4}+\mathrm{cosec}\frac {\alpha}{2}=\cot \frac {\alpha}{16} - \cot \frac {\alpha}{2}$$.

My Attempt:

$$\text{L.H.S}=\mathrm{cosec}\frac {\alpha}{8}+\mathrm{cosec}\frac {\alpha}{4} + \mathrm{cosec}\frac {\alpha}{2}$$
$$=\frac {1}{\sin(\alpha/8)} + \frac {1}{2\sin(\alpha/8)\cdot \cos(\alpha/8)} + \frac {1}{\sin (\alpha/2)}$$.
$$=\frac {2\cos (\alpha/8) +1}{2\sin(\alpha/8)\cdot\cos(\alpha/8)} + \frac {1}{\sin(\alpha/2)}$$.

How should I move on further? Please help.

Comment: Hint: $\csc x + \cot x = \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x} = \cot 2x$.

Comment: @rogerl, How do I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in general
$$\csc x + \cot x = \frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x} = \cot 2x.$$
Now, moving $\cot\frac{\alpha}{2}$ to the LHS and applying this identity multiple times gives
\begin{align}
  \csc\frac {\alpha}{8} + \csc\frac {\alpha}{4} + 
     \csc\frac {\alpha}{2} +  \cot \frac {\alpha}{2}
  &= \csc \frac{\alpha}{8} + \csc\frac{\alpha}{4} + \cot\frac{\alpha}{4} \\
  &= \csc \frac{\alpha}{8} + \cot\frac{\alpha}{8} \\
  &= \cot \frac{\alpha}{16}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

*Alternatively*, one may use
$$
\csc \frac {\alpha}{2}= \cot \alpha - \cot \frac {\alpha}{2}
$$ giving
$$
\csc \frac{\alpha}{2^{n}}= \cot \frac {\alpha}{2^{n+1}} - \cot \frac {\alpha}{2^{n}},\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots,
$$ then summing from $n=1$ to $n=3$ and using a [telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html) gives
$$
\csc \frac {\alpha}{8}+\csc \frac {\alpha}{4}+\csc \frac {\alpha}{2}=\cot \frac {\alpha}{16} - \cot \frac {\alpha}{2}.
$$

Comment: Do you have any other simpler method? I am not familiar with this process as it is not related to my grade.

Comment: +1, Simpler than this one?